# Rake db:create fails to connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to upload a rails app to heroku and I'm running into problems to change my app from sqlite3 to postgres, mainly when I run `rake db:create` I get:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

This is what my database.yml looks like:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: anagram_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: anagram_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: anagram_production
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have postgresql installed locally? If so, double check that it's running. Your database.yml file is also missing some required information to connect to a postgres database. You need to provide username, password and hostname.

Here's an example of mine which connects to a local postgres db:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_development
  pool: 10
  username: <%= %x(whoami) %>
  password:
```

For heroku/production, you can use the following:

```
production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
  pool: <%= ENV['DB_POOL'] || 10 %>
```